# How can I express this in another way?

Tags: american-english, speech

I want to express the following sentence in another way.

> The first algorithm was applied to obtain the norm solution by gradually decreasing the value of X.

Can anyone give me some help? Thank you.

Comment: Your sentence isn't bad.  Try rearranging the clauses, see if that helps it flow better. Something like "By gradually decreasing the value of X, the first algorithm was observed to converge on a solution."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first algorithm was applied **over** a gradually decreasing value of X to obtain the norm solution

*Over* is a good word to use when talking about ranges.

Comment: Not sure this is a good use of 'over'.  "Applied to a gradually decreasing..." might be better.